# Ubuntu 20.04 audio and video speed up over HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi

I remember seeing this issue on older version of Ubuntu (and do not remember if I ever fixed it successfully).

When playing media while the audio output is set to the analogue output, everything is fine. As soon as I switch to HDMI audio the sound and video speed up drastically (so far only tested on Twitch - which causes stuttering as I can't go past live footage).

I am using RX580. I tried relatives laptops (using both older and newer AMD hardware and using both 16.04 and 20.10, neither had an issue).

Can somebody point me in a direction of a definitive fix? The few results I found were ancient and did not fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple HDMI ports into your tower, try plugging into another. This solved the issue for me just now. I have an RX580 as well.